# SQL Server Duplicating rows with dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following three tables with parent-child relationship:

```
------------
|Company   |
------------
CompanyId

------------
|Agent     |
------------
AgentId
CompanyId

------------
|Work      |
------------
WorkId
AgentId
```

I would like to duplicate all records for given company, and insert into the same table, keeping the relationships. How should I approach this?

Comment: Are `CompanyId`, `AgentId` and `WorkId` identity columns? Do you want to duplicate all 3 tables? Are there any more columns in these tables (add at least one more for each table)

Comment: Why??? Are there no primary keys or other constraints to make sure such things do not happen?

Comment: @dotnetom Yes, they are identity columns. I want to duplicate records in all three tables with specific filter (duplicate all records/children of CompanyId 1 for example), and insert it into the same tables keeping the relations.

Comment: Why not use a view that joins the 3 tables? What is the real reason to create another table that might soon run out of synch with your existing tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get all entries in 3 tables.

```
SELECT C.CompanyId,A.AgentId,W.WorkId
FROM Company C
LEFT JOIN Agent A ON C.CompanyId=A.CompanyId
LEFT JOIN Work W ON A.AgentId=W.AgentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful what you ask for...

1. You may need to change * to a subset of fields for each table if a
   identity exists.
2. You will need to populate the '' with the companyID to duplicate. or possible remove the '' altogether
3. This assumes that CompanyID is not the identity.  Otherwise we have to carry that ID forward as we create the child records.

.

```
INSERT INTO company SELECT * FROM Company WHERE CompanyID = '';
INSERT INTO agent SELECT * FROM agent WHERE CompanyID = '';
INSERT INTO work SELECT * FROM work w WHERE exists 
   (SELECT 1 FROM agent a WHERE A.companyID='' and w.AgentID = a.AgentID);
```